# How to download GDB from minGW correctly?

Tags: windows, bash, c++, mingw, gdb

I am using GDB, downloaded from MinGW Installation Manager(I doubt it's installed correctly), to debug C++, and GDB cannot be found in the path below used to debug.

`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`

Other exes like GCC is present in the path and works.
Also, if I use the command of installation (mingw-get) in my MSYS2 MinGW cmd, it responds with `bash: mingw-get.exe: command not found.`

Is the issue related to a corrupt MinGW Installation Manager, or am I not installing it correctly?

Comment: have you actually searched your drive to see if gdb.exe is sitting there?  As in .. go to the root of C: and type`dir /s /b gdb.exe` and see if the thing is even on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check by restarting your PC, if it didn't work download the *.gdb file from its website (I guess it's a *.rar or some file), now update with `MSYS` and restart. It have solved for me, I guess it helps....

Answer (score 0):

No idea what `MinGW Installation Manager` is or why you were trying to use it when you are using msys2.

To install mingw64 gdb in msys2, you really just need to:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
```

You should probably run `pacman -Syu` **twice** before you run the above though.

As you can see, if you need other mingw64 builds of programs (toolchain programs or not), their package names would be prefixed with `mingw-w64-x86_64-`. There's also the package group `mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` which you can `pacman -S --needed` instead to get a somewhat full toolchain.

You may also want to use the `urt64` toolchain instead. See [this page](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) for more details. (You can e.g. `pacman -Ss gdb` to find out what's the package name prefix for each of the variants.)

Note that to use any of the toolchain (or any non-msys2 builds of programs), you should use the corresponding "launcher" of shell/terminal instead of msys2.exe.